# Multi-module clean architecture project: make Koin setup reflect proper gradle dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, koin

I am developing a multi-module project consisting out of these modules: domain, database, service and app.

The dependencies are as follows:

- domain has none
- database depends on domain
- service depends on database and domain
- app should only depend on domain and service, but now also depends on database.

app, service and database each have a modules.kt containing everything that module provides (Koin). database provides an implementation of the repository, service provides the use cases, app provides the viewmodels,...

The reason why app has to depend on the database module is so that when I start Koin in my app module, I can reference the databasemodule.

```
startKoin(this, listOf(
    appModule,
    databaseModule,
    serviceModule
), logger = AndroidLogger())
```

I don't want my app module to depend on my database module just for that. I do however still want every layer to have their own module file. Is there a way to declare that my Koin service module file depends on that database module file? That way my Koin setup mirrors my gradle setup.

Comment: Some answers and suggestions to this question can be found in the reddit thread:
(https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/akmawy/multimodule_clean_architecture_project_make_koin/)